# Do I need to reinstall Android Development Kit after enabling VT-x?

Tags: android, installation

I recently installed the Android application development tools on an new computer that has VT-x capabilities, and got a warning that they weren't turned on at the end, but it wasn't very clear about weather I should reinstall after enabling.
It gave me the option to launch after installing despite VT-x being turned off in the BIOS.

Comment: You don't need to reinstall it, just enable it and install HAXM again and this will most probably solve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I ran the installer again it gave me the option to uninstall everything and I couldn't untick the box next to the main component of the dev kit so I just reinstalled it all and made myself a cup of tea.
Everything seems to be working now.